# What is the most "Standard Library" method of asynchronous I/O stream with fixed buffer size in C++ (to implement producer-consumer model)?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost

The model could be decribed as a producer-consumer model, but with a fixed buffer size.

1. the solution is a method of byte stream(or object stream/queue is also good, even object stack is also good in my application), use like `std::stringstream`;
2. thread#1 produce bytes(objects), and thread#2 comsume the bytes(objects);
3. the buffer of the stream has a fixed size, to avoid large memory usage when the efficiency of two threads do not match.
4. when thread#1 call the `write()`, if there is not enough space in the buffer to store the bytes, thread#1 will be blocked, until all the bytes has been written to the stream;
5. when thread#2 call the `read()`, if there is not enough bytes in the buffer to read, thread#2 will be blocked, until enough bytes has been read from the stream.

I'm not willing to reinvent the wheel, so it's best to make the most of existing libraries, and if there is serveral ways, which one is the most formal and concise. Additionally, it would be better to use modern C++, like C++20 standard method, I am glad to learn new.

For optimal performance, I think a PingPong method is good, which needs a double-buffer. If I have to reinvent the wheel, I would choose this method, and synchronize the threads with a `std::binary_semaphore`.

I have found serveral methods that seems to meet my need, after a little wrapping:

1. derived from `std::basic_streambuf`, rewrite the methods `xsgetn()` and `xsputn()`, implement double-buffer, but need to reinvent the wheel which may introduce bugs;
2. use `boost::lockfree::queue/stack`, but the problem is it seems not able to set a fixed capacity.
3. use `boost::asio`, I know little about `boost::asio`, but I know it is a powerful lib of asynchronous model. is there a off-the-shelf solution in `boost::asio`?
4. use `std::coroutine`?

So is there any "Standard Library" way to implement asynchronous I/O stream?

Comment: When you ask for "optimal", you must also explain how you decide which solution is better or worse. Also, wouldn't it be preferable to have a *working* solution first, and only then think about making it *better* (according to some measure)?

Comment: @j6t Sorry for not explaining clearly. The "optimal" means most official. If there is a off-the-shelf STL or Boost solution, I think it's optimal, because it is on behalf of official(half official) implemention.

Comment: @j6t I changed the word "optimal" to "most 'STL'".

Comment: Boost's circular buffer (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) coupled with a mutex and two condition variables (read side + write side) sounds like it fits the bill. Of course a double buffer also works. I'm not aware of a prebuilt implementation in STD or Boost but it's not hard to make one. Do you want an example implementation of either?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the `STL` which only refers to the *containers* and *algorithms* parts of the `Standard Library`.